# Adding a vertical line at the maximum point in an excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to get Excel to create a vertical line at the maximum point in a graph. Note that this is not a point specified, but rather is between two points on a curve. How is this done?

Comment: I don't think Excel could do that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mate mentioned in the comments, Excel can't "automatically" find and plot a line.  However, it can be added without too much trouble.

1. First, make sure your chart is an XY(Scatter) chart type, not a Line Type.
2. Add your first data series, i.e. your prior curve.
3. Plot your maximum value as a second series, with only the max point.  If you know the value, but its just not plotted in the curve, add it directly.  If you don't know the value, use the formula for your curve to calculate it (ideally with Excel's solver, but you could also do it manually).
4. Format the point to your taste (make it either visible or not).
5. Add a vertical error bar for your vertical line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So basically we can draw the line but in a bit crude way.
Draw an XY(Scatter) chart type as it does not work with Line Type.
Add your first data series that makes the curve.
Plot your maximum value as a second series but with as many times as you used to draw the curve.